# How to find font in PSD?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I find which layers has a specific font family in a PSD with many layers, groups and several different font families?

Comment: slowly. frustratingly. confusingly. Alas, there's no easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to see what layers use what fonts.

You can make things a bit easier by using the filter options on the **Layer's Panel**

[image]

This will at least hide everything which is *not* a type layer. From there, you have to highlight the layers to see what font is in use.